# Jira: how to find all data associated with one issue?

Tags: jira

I need to move all data for one ticket from prod to test.
Is it possible to construct a query that pulls all data related to an issues provided? 
Anyone every tried it? Is it even possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with the REST API:

```
https://<jira-server>/rest/api/2/issue/<ISSUE-ID>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to do it via sql query(s)

Comment: Err.. then you will need to connect to the prod DB, update the local Db and so on. Why isn't this simple method OK? You get the exact same info

Comment: Probably because I did not want to deal with parsing and loading from Json. I feel more comfortable in d/b domain. Thank you for your help. All the data is there.